# Why google say my website is not good for phones

Tags: google-chrome, bootstrap-4, next.js, responsive, react-bootstrap

I have a website create with Next.js.
I use Bootstrap for responsive design and a little bit of SCSS.
When I go on this website with my phone (samsung s8) and other phones, all looks good and responsive too.
But Google say me:
The text of my website is too smaller,
Buttons are not separated,
and the content wider than screen...

I don't understand because when I look my website all is ok...
You can see website at: https://www.psweb.fr

Do you know why I have this warning of google?

Thanks for your help.

Stéphane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google looks at your UI/UX on the desktop and on the phone and checks for performance and accessibility. If google gives you a low rate on phones you need to improve your User Experience, not next.js.

Your website is open for improvement, the spacing between your items and the size of your fonts in certain areas are too large or too small; for example, the font and button size of your GDPR message(Cookies agreement prompt) is too small but your name and description fonts are too large.

Improving these problems might help you get a higher point and in case you want to continue to design your own website taking courses on UI/UX principles can help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your help, for me when I see my website on phone it's ok but I understand what you mean. I'll change it to a better ux/ui design 